# Cannot connect to mysql from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

The credentials are working from mysql workbench, but when I try it from PHP it takes a lot of time loading then gives 500 - internal server error.

```
$DB_HOST = some ip here (NOT localhost or 127.0.0.1) ;
$DB_USER = "myuser";
$DB_PASS = "mypassword";
$DB_NAME = "mydb";

$db = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);

mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$db) or  die("Error In database");
```

This was working on the dev server, but when moved to a new server it doesnt.

it might be useful to mention that the server runs PHP 5.4 so mysql_connect works fine.

I appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Is was the dev server on the same host as the db? And does it give you an sql error?

Comment: did you looked in your error log files? Perhaps reason not in connection. Maybe htaccess  or something else

Comment: Please try with $DB_HOST = "localhost"; instead of ip.

Comment: @Trudbert the host is different than the DB, it doesnt give any errors, just takes a bit of time then gives 500 internal server error

Comment: @emmanuel wont work because the host is different than mysql

Comment: Are the dev and the new server on the same host?

Comment: @Trudbert no they are not

Comment: Was the dev server on the DB host?

Comment: If you get a 500 error, look at the error logs of your webserver. There usually is a clear message what the problem is.

Comment: @Trudbert yes, but we never used localhost, always ips

Comment: Another note: the `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. You should not write new code using them. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: @VasilVanchuk I dont have access to logs now, but I'm sure its the connection, as I tried running php pages with no connection and work fine

Comment: Are you sure the user@newserver exists for mysql?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for the note, its not my choice though

Comment: @Trudbert yes, works fine on workbench

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Does workbench run the new server? If not have you checked the firewall settings for the new server?

Comment: Does the user you are trying to login as have appropriate permissions to login to a remote server?

Comment: @Trudbert will check firewall settings, thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 0):

if you use cpanel as your hosting, you have to set database user in MYSQLDATABASE menu
then you have to use prefix in DBUser and DBName like 'user_table' and 'user_db'